# cal value for each li element

Tags: jquery, html

What I have is that my jquery is creating automatic `<li>` elements. Each `<li>` element contains 1 select box and 1 input box. So what I want is it should go into each `<li>` element and then it should multiply the number of select boxes and input boxes and give me a of this multiplication for each `<li>` element. I have used the jquery `each()` function for `<li>` as well as both select and input boxes. But its showing same value for every

`enter code here`.

```
<li class="working">
    </span><span class="dd">

    <h3>Select Photo Size for above picture:</h3>

    <select class="price">
        <option value=".20" class="sz">6x4 (€0.20)</option>
        <option value="0.30" class="sz">5x7 (€0.20)</option>
        <option value="3.49" class="sz">8x6 (€3.49)</option>
    </select>


    <h3>Select quantity for above size:</h3>

    </span>

    <input type="text" name="qt" class="qt">

    <h3>Per Photo Price:</h3>

    </span>

    <h3 class="pr"></h3>

    <input type="text" class="knb" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+ ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" />

    <p class="ss"></p>

    <span class="close"></span>
</li>




$('.qt').each(function() {
       if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 1 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 99 &&
     $('.price').val() == '.20')
    {
        var a = $('.qt').val();
        var b = '.15';
        var c = a * b;
        $('.pr').text(c);
    }
    else if(parseInt($('.qt').val()) >= 100 && parseInt($('.qt').val()) <= 200 &&
     $('.price').val() == '.20')
    {
        alert('Its greater');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like the following:

<s>**Please note** that without your html structure, I haven't changed the `$('.pr')` selector or the `$('.price')` selector so all your `.pr` will be set to the last `.qt` calculation.</s>

I would imagine these selectors to be something like `$(this).siblings('.pr')` -> if `pr` is on the same level of elements as `qt`.  If it is in a table on a different cell it would be something like this: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.pr')`

**Updated given your html**

```
$('.qt').each(function() {
   var qtVal = parseInt(this.value),
       li = $(this).closest('li');

   if (li.find('.price').val() == '.20') {  
     if (qtVal >= 1 && qtVal <= 99) {
       var a = qtVal;
       var b = '.15';
       var c = a * b;
       li.find('.pr').text(c);              
     } else if (qtVal >= 100 && qtVal <= 200) {
       alert('Its greater');
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: As you didn't format your code above, I missed a span tag hidden in amongst it.  Have edited the answer, should work now

Comment: I have formatted the HTML code, it was unreadable. It showed up lonely </span> elements.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah, I saw them when I put it into a fiddle and pressed the tidy button. This is why I went the closest route, bit more generic and will allow for strange orphans!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `parseInt($('.qt').val())` with `parseInt($(this).val())`, since you're iterating each element. `$('.qt')` represents *all* `'.qt'` together.

Improvement tip :

Since you're executing `parseInt($('.qt').val())` multiple times (that should be replaced by `$(this).val()`, as I said), do it only once and store it in a variable.

```
$('.qt').each(function() {

   var amount = parseInt($(this).val()),
       priceVal = $('.price').val();

   if(priceVal == '.20'){
      if(amount >= 1 && amount <= 99){
         var a = $('.qt').val(),
             b = '.15',
             c = a * b;
         $('.pr').text(c);
      }else if(amount <= 200){
         alert('Its greater');
      }
   }
});
```

Besides, `if(amount >= 100)` is useless, because it has already failed the `if(amount <= 99)` test, so it is necessarily >=100. I have also factorized `if(priceVal == '.20')`.

**EDIT**

Okay, now I have your HTML code and it really does't match what the JS code would suggest...

You're iterating `.qt`, not `li` elements. `.qt` are input fields, not `li`.

```
$("li.working").each( function(){
     var $this = $(this),
         selectedPrice = parseInt($this.find("select.price").val()),
         quantity = parseInt($this.find("input.qt").val());

     totalPrice = selectedPrice * quantity; 

      $this.find("h3.pr").text(totalPrice);

});
```

There are weird `</span>` and reverted `</span><span class="dd">` elements in your generated code, I strongly suggest to check it out and clean it up.

Comment: That would be easier if you also shared the HTML code, so we don't have to guess it.

Comment: ...that would be easier if you also shared the HTML code, so we don't have to guess it.

Comment: edited my question and i have added html which automatically generated by jquery